# "Future#WaitForCompletion" while running a powershell script from GitHub - Terraform

Tags: azure, powershell, terraform, cloud

I have a powershell script present in GitHub and using it in the "Settings" block inside "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" to configure the Windows Server VM. Below is the code.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "iis-windows-vm" {
 depends_on           = [azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.web-windows-vm]
 name                 = "win-${random_string.random-win-vm.result}-vm-extn"
 virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.web-windows-vm.id
 publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
 type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
 type_handler_version = "1.9"

   settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File demo.ps1",
        "fileUris": ["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Configure/app/master/demo.ps1"]
    }
SETTINGS
}
```

And the below are the content of "demo.ps1"

```
New-LocalUser "ansible" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force ) -AccountNeverExpires:$true -PasswordNeverExpires:$true -FullName "ansible" | Add-LocalGroupMember -Group administrators

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"
$file = "$env:temp\ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"

(New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $file)

powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File $file

Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools
```

When I do "terraform apply", below error is displayed.

```
Error: Future#WaitForCompletion: context has been cancelled: StatusCode=200 -- Original Error: context deadline exceeded
```

The code was working fine until now. Not able to figure out the problem here. Request you assist me to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

The error `Original Error: context deadline exceeded` means that we ran into a situation where a given action was **not completed in an expected timeframe**.

So there can be a handful of reason why you are encountering the execution timeout like **Network Latency, Slow I/O, Firewall Rules** and many more. One possible reason that I think is the URL is not responding as expected or it's taking to much time to respond.

**Before being able to solve the problem, you need to determine what is actually failing**. I would suggest to check the detailed terraform log file to find the reason of timeout.

But even after checking you find is good and you are still facing the issue then with **v2.0 of the AzureRM Provider** it is possible to add custom timeouts using `timeouts` block as shown in the example snippet below.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resource-group"
  location = "West Europe"

  timeouts {
    create = "10m"
    delete = "30m"
  }
}
```

For more information check this [Custom Timeouts for Resources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/2.0-upgrade-guide#custom-timeouts-for-resources) section of the terraform document.